# Force nginx to always autoindex and ignore index.html files?

Tags: nginx, configuration, directoryindex

I am trying to get nginx to ignore `index.html` files and **always** show a directory listing from the `autoindex` module.

If I remove my `index` line, nginx still defaults to serving `index.html` files, so that is not a solution.

A similar question [was asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166131/how-can-i-force-autoindex-and-ignore-index-html-files), but I am looking for a solution that does not involve inventing a bogus file name, if such a solution exists (not to mention the thread is off topic there).

How can I change my `index` directive to tell nginx to never show index files?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. As far as I can tell I've asked a clear, understandable question that is not a dupe and is on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of removing the `index` directive, you should set it to a name which is not reasonably expected to exist, so that it never matches any file.

For example:

```
index X6XewZMsmreGIxx1lCdp0Yo1X4qHTivW;
```

You may not *like* this solution. It is a little inelegant. But it works well and does exactly what you want, while nothing else does.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you are sure that there is no more elegant solution, then I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: At this point I'm sure there is no other more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove (comment out) the index directive.  With for example the Debian nginx package, autoindex (or fancyindex)  attempts a directory index.

As an alternative, bogus index file isn't elegant, but it isn't expensive either. Probably only needs a couple system calls to check file non existence.